# unable to get value that is set in a callback

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having an issue getting a value that is set in a callback. I initially make a call to get Quest data, then call `game.state.setNPCs` after the quest data has returned.

I want to get the NPC object after it has been set, but the get is returning an empty array even though `setNPCs()` seems to be setting the array.

You can see below, after the `callback` to set the `result.npcs`, I log out `getNPCs()`, and it is an Empty Array.

Even more weird, I call `game.state.getNPCs()` from within the `GameState` object after the value has been set, but it is still an empty array.

**EDIT**: I find if I pass in `game.state.getNPCs` as a callback into the initial callback `setNPCs()`, like so:

```
callback(result.npcs, game.state.getNPCs);
```

Then this works... But I don't want to have to pass in another callback. See below.

---

Initial call with `game.state.setNPCs` callback:

```
Utilities.game.quest.getQuestData({ id : stat.quest_id }, game.state.setNPCs);
```

Call to getQuestData:

```
getQuestData : function (params, setNPCcallback) {

    API.Quest.getQuestData(params).done(function (result) {

        if (game.state) {

            game.state.setQuest(result); //Object received successfully

            setNPCcallback(result.npcs, game.state.getNPCs); 

            console.log('NPCs', game.state.getNPCs()); //Empty array
        }
    });
},
```

GameState object:

```
var GameState = function(args) {
      this.npcs = [];
      ...
};

GameState.prototype = {

    constructor : GameState,

    getNPCs : function () {
        console.log(this.npcs); //Empty array
        return this.npcs;
    },

    setNPCs : function (npcsArray, getNPCcallback) {
        this.npcs = npcsArray;
        console.log(this.npcs); //Contains Object
        console.log(game.state.getNPCs()); //Empty array
        console.log(getNPCcallback()); //Contains Object
    },
```

Comment: Where are you calling `setNPCs` ..?

Comment: @TJ in the initial `getQuestData`, I pass in a callback `Utilities.game.quest.getQuestData({ id : stat.quest_id }, game.state.setNPCs);`. See top of post

Comment: @TJ also see above edit. It works if I pass in `game.state.getNPCs` as a callback into `game.state.setNPCs`... but this looks bad and I'm wondering why I can't just get the value after `setNPCs` has been called. It's not like it's fetching data from the server again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small demo to test the issue.

```
var Person = function () {
    this.name = "someone";
}
Person.prototype.walk = function () {
    console.log(this)
};
var p = new Person;

function exec(callback) {
    callback(); //context is Window
    callback.call(p); //context is Person {name: "someone"}
}
p.walk(); //context is Person {name: "someone"}
exec(p.walk);
```

When you invoke the callback from `getQuestData`, the context is not `GameState` instance. Invoking the callback with the correct context using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) methods, or using a callback which is bound to correct context using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method should fix the issue.

Else you can pass the `GameState` instance itself and invoke `gameState.callbackMethod()`

which should look like the following according to previous example

```
function exec(instance) {
  instance.walk(); //context is Person {name: "someone"}
}
exec(p);
```

Comment: Thanks! Oops forgot about context